# Creating a account system that runs on every computer js

Tags: javascript

I tried to do a account system to my website (the site does not store in a domain).
I tried to save the accounts details with "localStorage" but those variables do not created on every computer, and when i took the same files to another computer the variables were not exist.
What can I do for those variables (accounts) be on any computer i run the website on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a database like [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/collateral/mongodb-3-2-whats-new?jmp=search&utm_source=google&utm_campaign=US-Brand-Alpha&utm_keyword=mongodb&utm_device=c&utm_network=g&utm_medium=cpc&utm_creative=86031857323&utm_matchtype=e&gclid=CjwKEAjwlfO3BRDR4Pj_u-iO2U0SJAD88y1SEKlpZXp4lSAAV1I2fcRdWvzdomNyM5WbGtlhb2SV5BoC12Pw_wcB) or [MySQL](https://www.mysql.com/).

Push variables to the DB and Pull them down as necessary. These systems can be run on your local machine. Local storage is not sufficient for what you are attempting.